# Maven/Jetty to Maven/Tomcat Project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project that I created with the Maven Archetype plugin and I added the Maven Jetty plugin so I can run the jetty server with "mvn jetty:run-war".

Now I have to change my project so that it integrates with Eclipse and Tomcat.  I remember working on some projects which when I clicked the Tomcat button from the [Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html), it would automatically compile the new code, deploy it to the Tomcat's webapp folder, and start the Tomcat server for you.  Using tomcat also allows us to use the integrated Eclipse debugger.

How do I get that effect with my current Maven/Jetty setup without re-creating the entire project over again and starting it as a Tomcat project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html). It has similar goals to the `jetty` plugin.  You just need to add the `plugin configuration` to your existing pom and make no additional changes.